# $ionicModal.fromtemplateUrl not fire then

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Hi I need to show  a popup in my ionic application, Ifollowed the documentation: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/;
but fromTemplateUrl seems do not fire then, so the popup does not show up because my $scope.modal.show is undefined.this is an extract of my code:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/loginPopup.html', {
                                                  scope: $scope,
                                                  animation: 'slide-in-up'
                                                }).then(function(modal) {
                                                  $scope.modal = modal;
                                                  console.log('then ionicmodal')
                                                },function(err) {
                                                    console.log('errore promessa',err); // Error: "It broke"
                                                  });
```

it is pretty regular,
Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What's the console error?

Comment: 'templates/loginPopup.html' might need to be '/templates/loginPopup.html'

Comment: @Joe No, Ionic handles the relative paths. The OP needs to check that _loginPopup.html_ is in _www/templates/_.

Comment: Hi,  I tried what you said, same result, the console error:  TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at Scope.$scope.openModal (wodCtrl.js:46)
  at new <anonymous> (wodCtrl.js:58)
  at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:12104)
  at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:12112)
  at ionic.bundle.js:16381
  at hint.js:1544
  at self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:47316)
  at Object.switcher.render (ionic.bundle.js:45595)
  at Object.switcher.init (ionic.bundle.js:45515)
  at self.render (ionic.bundle.js:47204)
 2015-09-26 16:39:51.477wodCtrl.js:26 wodctrl